# How can i change the SSL configuration in IIS on Windows 11?

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7.5

I created a website in IIS using the following code:

I exported a certificate from IIS under Server Certificates to use:

```
name = "TestSite"
port = 5858
location = location of my install files.


 using (ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager())
 {        
    Site website = iisManager.Sites.Add(name, location, port); 
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"c:\certs\testwcf.pfx", 
      "pwd>");
    store.Add(certificate);
    var binding = website.Bindings.Add("*:443:", certificate.GetCertHash(), store.Name);
    binding.Protocol = "https";
    store.Close();
    website.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName = appPoolName;
    website.ServerAutoStart = true;
    iisManager.CommitChanges();
 }
```

Now whats happening is that if i run any other development solutions from Visual Studio
I get the error:

```
  "An error occurred while using SSL configuration for endpoint 0.0.0.0:87879.  The 
   error status code is contained within the returned data."
```

When the development site comes up it redirects to localhost and I cant seem to reach https://localhost:87879, which uses IIS Express.

I am not sure how but I think i have broken something in the bindings in IIS which is affecting localhost
Where can i start to look at this any ideas ?

Comment: Probably you broke port 87879's HTTP API mapping, so you might see if you can find something there, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#ip-based-bindings

Comment: tried using this tool, all it says is that all under HTTP API all the Certificate Status is "broken" from the MY store. Where do i even start to try and fix this ?

Comment: I have a certificate that i want to import , where  in the menus can i import it .. I tried to view certificate on the port number but it does nothing

Comment: Jesus Manager is more of a diagnostics tool, so to modify the settings for port 87879 you should stick to your own C# code and modify that accordingly.

Comment: thats just it from the code i added a certificate to a store and used it on port 87879 with 443 bindings ...  At the moment i dont really know what to do .. I can write the code no problem, but what  to do is the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it going.
For any one having this issue try the following:

From an elevated command prompt run:

> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express IisExpressAdminCmd.exe
> setupsslUrl -url:urlToYourSite -UseSelfSigned

Replacing urlToYourSite with your url.

e.g.

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express
IisExpressAdminCmd.exe setupsslUrl -url:https://localhost:44387/ -UseSelfSigned